# Prove A=A* where $Ax = \sum_{n}a_{n}\langle x, u_n \rangle u_n =0 $ iff $a_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators, dual-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

How to prove A=A* where $Ax = \sum_{n}a_{n}\langle x, u_n \rangle u_n=0 $ iff $a_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $[u_n]$ is an orthonormal sequence?

Edit: does it have something to do with the equality: $\langle Ax, y \rangle = \langle x, A^*y \rangle  = \overline{\langle A^*y, x \rangle} $?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\langle x,Ay\rangle=
\langle x,\sum_{n}a_n\langle y, u_n\rangle u_n\rangle
=\sum_{n} \overline{a_n\langle y,u_n\rangle}\langle x,u_n\rangle
=\sum_{n} \overline{\langle y,\overline{a_n}\langle x,u_n\rangle u_n\rangle}
=\sum_{n} \overline{\langle y,a_n\langle x,u_n\rangle u_n\rangle}
=\overline{\langle y,Ax \rangle}=\langle Ax,y\rangle$$

$A$ represents a diagonal matrix with all elements real numbers.

Comment: What am i missing? There is no use of A* (A dual/adjoint)

Comment: think i got it. Add to the left hand side <Ax,y>=<x,A*y>